# Why can I no longer show end time in event when using the new version of jquery fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I just upgraded from version [1.6.4 to 2.2 of jquery Fullcalenda](http://fullcalendar.io/)r and I am running into an issue with displaying start and end time

1. I can no longer see end time when I want to show the start and end time on event.  Here is a screenshot with 1.6.4 where I have an event from midnight to 7:59 AM and that shows both.

[image]

and here is the same event displayed with 2.2 and its not showing the end time (it seems to show the start time twice)

[image]

here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next title today',
        right: ''
    },
    lazyFetching: false,
    editable: false,
    theme: false,
    timeFormat: 'H:mm{-H:mm} ',
    height: 350,
```

I reviwed the upgrade guide and the latest documentation and I don't see anything has changed around rendering timeFormat 'H:mm{-H:mm} '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set this options:

```
timeFormat: 'H:mm',
displayEventEnd:true,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8p9g6duw/1/

View events for Wednesday

Comment: thanks . . I am not sure why this is not listed in the upgrade guide